# How to redraw chart every x seconds with MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, mpandroidchart

I have a pie chart ([MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)) getting data through Volley and I am using the following to update the chart every 3 seconds but the chart is not getting re drawn. This is all located within a fragment which is shown in a tab view. The chart only refreshes when I click another tab and go back to it. It doesn't redraw itself while I am on the page.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_device_current_report, container, false);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new AttemptJson().execute();
            }
        }, 3000);
        return layout;
    }
```

I have an inner class AttemptJson:

```
class AttemptJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            updateChart();
            return "";
        }
    }
```

This is my updateChart method which grabs the JSON file and stores it using Volley.

```
private void updateChart() {

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,

                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray dataset = response.getJSONArray("dataset");
                            JSONArray time = response.getJSONArray("time");

                            JSONArray temp = dataset.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("data");
                            JSONArray humid = dataset.getJSONObject(1).getJSONArray("data");
                            for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {
                                float temp_data = Float.parseFloat(temp.getJSONObject(i).getString("value"));
                                float time_data = Float.parseFloat(time.getJSONObject(i).getString("time"));

                                temperature.add(new Entry(time_data, temp_data));
                            }
                            float data = (float)(Float.parseFloat(humid.getJSONObject(humid.length()-1).getString("value")) + Math.random()*20 - 5);
                            if(humidity.size() != 0) humidity.clear();
                            humidity.add(new PieEntry(data));
                            humidity.add(new PieEntry(100 - data));

                            drawGraph();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.d("debug", "Object dataset is incorrect");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },

                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });
        requestQueue.add(req);
    }
```

In that method I call drawGraph() to draw the actual graph:

```
private void drawGraph() {
        LineChart temperatureChart;
        PieChart humidityChart;

        LineDataSet lineDataSet1 = new LineDataSet(temperature, "temperature");
        lineDataSet1.setDrawCircles(false);
        lineDataSet1.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        lineDataSet1.setDrawValues(false);

        temperatureChart = (LineChart) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.curr_chart_temp);
        humidityChart = (PieChart) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.curr_chart_humid);

        temperatureChart.setData(new LineData(lineDataSet1));
        temperatureChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinimum(-50f);
        temperatureChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMaximum(50f);
        temperatureChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
        temperatureChart.animateX(2000);
        temperatureChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(400);
        temperatureChart.invalidate();

        PieDataSet dataset = new PieDataSet(humidity,"Humidity");
        dataset.setColors(new int[]{Color.RED,Color.WHITE});
        PieData humidValue= new PieData(dataset);
        humidValue.setDrawValues(false);
        humidityChart.setData(humidValue);
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        humidityChart.setCenterText( df.format(humidity.get(0).getValue()) + "%");
        humidityChart.setDrawCenterText(true);
        humidityChart.animateY(1000);

    }
```

Comment: view real time chart sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `findViewById` to get a handle on a View  as a function-local variable repeatedly is not the correct approach in Android. Your current code is updating a separate instance of `LineChart` from the one displayed on the screen.

Instead, make `LineChart` and `PieChart` class fields.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private final LineChart lineChart;
    private final PieChart pieChart;

    public View onCreateView() {  
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_device_current_report, container, false);  
        lineChart = layout.findViewById(R.id.curr_chart_temp);
        pieChart = layout.findViewById(R.id.curr_chart_humid);
        //insert the rest of your onCreate() code
    }
}
```

Then in `updateChart()` you can use the rest of the code apart from the declaration of `LineChart`,`PieChart` and the `findViewById`. Don't forget to call `notifyDatasetChanged()` after you modify the dataset.